# Can a global Shortcut .lnk be created programmatically?

Tags: c#, shortcut-file

I am currently creating a shortcut programmatically, however I want to know if it is possible in C# to create a global shortcut in a similar way.

Below is my code:

```
WshShell shell = new WshShell();
string shortcutLocation = "pathToShortcut//Shortcut1.lnk"
IWshShortcut shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutLocation);
shortcut.Arguments = "foo bar";
shortcut.Description = "Test Shortcut";
shortcut.TargetPath = "pathToShortcutExe";
shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "pathToWorkingDirectory"
shortcut.Save();
```

This code works great to create a shortcut for the user, but I want to know if there exists a way to do this for the system. I've seen globally installed programs place shortcuts on all Users, so I'm curious how to achieve this effect in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can..
you must add a reference Project > Add Reference > COM > Windows Script Host Object Model.

```
    using IWshRuntimeLibrary;

    private void CreateShortcut()
    {
      object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
      WshShell shell = new WshShell();
      string shortcutAddress = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\Notepad.lnk";
      IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
      shortcut.Description = "New shortcut for a Notepad";
      shortcut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Shift+N";
      shortcut.TargetPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolders.System) + @"\notepad.exe";
      shortcut.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on what the shDesktop object is? That seems to be the major difference in what you added. +1

Comment: Also I'm curious as to how this makes the shortcut global?

Comment: It's basically a string, it's content is "Desktop", so we could add a reference to that object to be able to call it in SpecialFolders.Item() function

Comment: because the parameter must be an object.. check this url https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea7b5xe(v=vs.84).aspx
If I could help you please accept my solution

Comment: I haven't accepted because I haven't been able to verify it works yet. I've ran the code and it creates a notepad shortcut on my desktop, but not on any of the other users desktop. I also looked into the article you linked and saw that you can swap the shell special folders to other options and I used "AllUsersDesktop" instead, and I think perhaps this will work, but still haven't been able to verify